# From view to child table view

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationbar

Can I start with a view based based app and when a button is touched jump to a "child view" with a NavigationBar and the back button to go back the main view?

also...would this be a violation of apple's store rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - the trick is to have your navigation controller always present, but to use

```
setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO
```

to make it hidden in your root view. In the child views you get there by pushing them as normal but use

```
setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES
```

in their `viewWillAppear`. (tweak the animated property to make it look the way you prefer)

I don't think it violates any rules, I have used it in an app with a visual main menu that pushes child views and can pop them to return to that visual main menu showing no navigation bar.

Comment: Did you create and initialize the nav controller with your base view? It needs to have a root view even though you don't see the bar in your root view. Then you should be able to push with the lines you have shown.

Comment: Alright I got it to move to the next view with this
'UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]         initWithRootViewController:[[CreateCardView alloc]             initWithNibName:@"CreateCardView" bundle:nil]];'
'[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];' 
One LAST thing. The back button is not displaying at all. How do I get an instance to the NavController? or how do i add the actual button?

Comment: OK - I don't think you want presentModal... if this is your root view. Have you tried making your nav controller's view your application delegate's window's subview, like [window addSubview:navController.view]; ?

Comment: Alright, so I ended up creating a new NavigationBased Project removed the tableView and added a regular view instead. Followed what you said about hiding the bar on `viewWillAppear` and I didn't  have to worry about the navController.  It just worked. Thanks so much!